# Securely send a php form without https?

Tags: php, forms, security, hash, https

I am new to website security and I need to make a registration and login system.  I am not yet using https for it, how can I make my registration secure?

This is my registration form, index.php, I use ajax to pass the form values to create_account.php .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'create_account.php', data:$('#ContactForm').serialize(), success: function(response) {
        $('#ContactForm').find('.form_result').html(response);
    }});

    return false;
}

</script>
<form id="ContactForm" onsubmit="return submitForm();" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="fname" value=""/> 
   <input type="text" name="lname" value="" />
   <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
   <input type="text" name="vEmail" value="" /> 
   <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
   <input type="password" name="vPassword" value="" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="password.value=sha256_hash(password.value)"/>
<div class="form_result">
```

I tried onclick="password.value=sha256_hash(password.value)" but it doesn't work at all.
Now I am unsure about how an attacker can get the information sent from index.php to create_account.php.  Is it possible to hash (sha256/512) and salt it with javascript?
In create_account.php, I am already doing this type of security.

If it is not possible, how can we set https (I know almost nothing about ssl)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am not yet using https for it, how can I make my registration secure?

Start using HTTPS. Any other approach is madness and won't be secure.

> I tried onclick="password.value=sha256_hash(password.value)" but it doesn't work at all.

Sending a hashed password will contribute very little to security. It will reduce (although not by a significant amount) the risk of attackers finding out what password the user is using  (which will help defend users who recycle passwords) but if they sniff it in transit then they can still know what string they need to send to your site to log in as that user.

> Is it possible to hash (sha256/512) and salt it with javascript?

Possible? Yes. Useful as a means to solve this problem? Not even slightly.

If you want security, get SSL support.

> If it is not possible, how can we set https (I know almost nothing about ssl)?

The basic approach is:

1. Buy or generate a certificate (generating your own will result in problems since it won't be signed by someone the average user's browser trusts)
2. Configure your server to use the certificate (how you do this depends on the server, Google is your friend here, it can find things like [these instructions for setting up SSL for Apache HTTPD on a Debian system](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/349)).

Comment: _"Any other approach is madness"_, +1 indeed.

Comment: I disagree with the strict statement that salted hashing could not improve security -- it's possible to implement a challenge/response scheme in JS which could reasonably protect against _passive_ attacks (but not active attacks). Of course I totally agree with the strong advice to use SSL instead of rolling something wacky and anything else you wrote, so I upvoted anyway.

Comment: Ok, I'll check your website for the SSL certificate, I'll get back to you you on that.  So if I put SSL, what will be the security flaws left?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm sure you could salt the password client side before sending it, that's not going to do much for you in terms of security. Yes it will prevent the original password from being snooped in transit, but that also exposes your hash-salt to anyone with an internet connection, so they could just rainbow table to steal passwords. Assuming you still choose to do that, do you want to rehash every time someone tries to log in? You're just better to by an SSL certificate and set it up.

As for setting up SSL, I quickly googled and came across [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_7340693_configure-ssl-php.html). If you're just testing yourself you should be fine [generating your own certificate](http://www.openssl.org/docs/HOWTO/certificates.txt), however if you are going to production you will need to buy a certificate from a registered provider (like verisign). As well, whatever hosting provider you're using may force you to use a purchased one even during testing.

Again, if you're using a shared hosting provider you may need to ask them for help installing your certificate.

Comment: I disagree with the statement about rainbow tables; proper salting prevents rainbow tables from being useful to the attacker. Of course exhaustive search is possible, but rainbow tables are not going to help the attacker.

Comment: I agree that proper salting prevents rainbow tables, however if you are salting/hashing it on the client machine, then your salt is exposed in your javascript. It is now useless as a salt. This is not proper salting.

Comment: Salts are not meant to be secret.

Comment: Fair enough, after reading more my salts are just done using a secret salt which is reused. This allowed me to do a few tricks but it seems aren't right. I'll have to reconsider some of my choices.... thanks for the heads up.